# ELAN touchpad of Asus X571 not correctly working with Unity on Ubuntu 19.10, no soft touch

Tags: unity, mouse, touchpad

the touch pad of my Asus X571 seems to be not identified as touchpad when I am using the Unity desktop. So instead of the touch pad settings I am seeing only mouse settings in system configuration (Primary button, Double click speed).

However, when I start with Ubuntu (Gnome) desktop, everything is all right! Soft touch works and I can see the full touch pad configuration options.

With Unity desktop, only two-finger-scroll and the mechanical buttons are working. Soft touch is not working.

I found this page https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection but since the problem only occurs with Unity, it does not seem to be a kernel problem. Where do I start to fix this?
Found many similar questions here too, but none seems to see a touchpad malfunction only with Unity desktop.

```
/proc/bus/input/devices
N: Name="ELAN1200:00 04F3:3104 Touchpad"
P: Phys=i2c-ELAN1200:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-1/i2c-ELAN1200:00/0018:04F3:3104.0001/input/input11

xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN1200:00 04F3:3104 Touchpad            id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]

xinput list-props 11
Device 'ELAN1200:00 04F3:3104 Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (198):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (200): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (335): 0
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (336): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (337):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (338):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (339):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (340):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (341):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (342):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (343):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (344):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (345):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (346):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (347):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (348):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (349):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Click Methods Available (350): 1, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled (351):    1, 0
    libinput Click Method Enabled Default (352):    1, 0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (353):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (354):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (355): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (356): 0.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (357): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (358): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (320): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (321):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (322):    0, 0
    Device Node (323):  "/dev/input/event8"
    Device Product ID (324):    1267, 12548
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (359):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (360):   1
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this bug by adding this command to Startup Applications:

```
xinput set-prop "ELAN1200:00 04F3:3104 Touchpad" "libinput Tapping Enabled" 1
```

However at *System Settings / Mouse & Touchpad* there still are no touchpad controls shown.